# Logging con timezone Europe/Madrid Flask

Tags: python, datetime, flask, log

Estoy intentando cambiar el timezone del logging de Flask pero no soy capaz.
He probado inicialmente a colocar en create_app la sentencia

```
TIMEZONE='Europe/Madrid'
```

pero no se cambia el log. También he probado a sobreescribir la clase Formatter de logging:

```
class Formatter(logging.Formatter):
    """override logging.Formatter to use an aware datetime object"""
    def converter(self, timestamp):
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        tzinfo = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
        return tzinfo.localize(dt)
        
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        dt = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = dt.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            try:
                s = dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
            except TypeError:
                s = dt.isoformat()
        return s
```

pero sigue apareciendo un tiempo con dos horas atrás de diferencia.
¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?
Mi archivo de logging es:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


class PVCLogger(TimedRotatingFileHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('pvc-back.log', 'midnight', 1)
        self.prefix = '%Y%m%d'
        self.setFormatter(
            logging.Formatter(
                '%(asctime)s %(filename)-18s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s'
            )
        )
```

Un ejemplo es el siguiente:
Aparece el datetime
2022-08-18 **11**:01:47,251
cuando debería aparecer
2022-08-18 **13**:01:47,251

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución finalmente.
El problema es que al inicializar el logger y, al estar trabajando sobre Docker, la hora no es la que deseaba.
En la clase Formatter he incluido la llamada

```
time.tzset()
```

antes de la clase Formatter y he añadido al Docker-compose una variable que utiliza la libreria Time para setear el timezone.
En resumen, lo que sucedía es que al inicializar el logger en Docker, al no haber una variable TZ con un timezone concreto, cogía el predeterminado.
Al haber incluido esa variable en el docker-compose

```
- TZ=Europe/Madrid
```

y al ejecutar la sentencia(que coge la variable de entorno y setea en base al timezone que se encuentra en ella) actualiza el timezone.